# What is the relationship between ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit and system.net connectionManagement maxconnection?

Tags: .net, web-config, system.net, machine.config, .net-4.7

Do these two settings refer to the same limit or seperate limits? (don't fixate on the number, I put that in at random)

```cs
System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 20;
```

The above property which can be set in code, 
and the optional configuration section below (in web.config or machine.config):

```xml
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="localhost" maxconnection="20"/>
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
```

More background:
We're looking at the performance of an existing ASP.Net (MVC 5?) web application that is under increasing load. The service makes calls to other services/dependencies, which appear to be being capped. We don't know if that cap is out-bound from our service, or inbound at the dependencies, or somewhere else (network or something).

We have a good load test environment, so we can change settings and measure their affect, but it takes quite a long time (a couple of hours) to make, deploy and measure a change, so we would like to understand what is a good candidate for change, and understand how our changes work.

The above two settings caught our eye as possible things to adjust and load test because of the apparently capped outgoing requests to our dependencies. However we don't understand if these are changing the same limit, or different limits?

And if they are different limits - is increasing just one going to have no affect (because the other limit is still there)?
There is also some confusion about the defaults - but let's leave that out-of-scope for this question to keep it focused.